# how to find out the method definition of torch.nn.Module.parameters()

Tags: pytorch

I am following [this notebook](https://github.com/udacity/deep-learning-v2-pytorch/blob/master/recurrent-neural-networks/char-rnn/Character_Level_RNN_Exercise.ipynb):

One of the method:

```
def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
    ''' Initializes hidden state '''
    # Create two new tensors with sizes n_layers x batch_size x n_hidden,
    # initialized to zero, for hidden state and cell state of LSTM
    weight = next(self.parameters()).data
    
    if (train_on_gpu):
        hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.n_hidden).zero_().cuda(),
              weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.n_hidden).zero_().cuda())
    else:
        hidden = (weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.n_hidden).zero_(),
                  weight.new(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.n_hidden).zero_())
    
    return hidden
```

I would like to see what type of ***weight*** is and how to use `new()` method, so I was trying to find out the `parameters()` method as the data attribute comes from `paramerters()` method.

Surprisingly, I cannot find where it comes from after reading the source code of [nn module](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/tree/master/torch/nn) in PyTorch.

How do you figure out where to see the definition of methods you saw from PyTorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so I was trying to find out the parameters() method as the data
> attribute comes from paramerters() method.
> Surprisingly, I cannot find where it comes from after reading the
> source code of nn module in PyTorch.

You can see the module definition under `torch/nn/modules/module.py` here at [line 178](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L178).
You can then easily spot the `parameters()` method [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L1087).

> How do you guys figure out where to see the definition of methods you
> saw from PyTorch?

The easiest way that I myself always use, is to use VSCode's `Go to Definition` or its `Peek -> Peek definition` feature.
I believe Pycharm has a similar functionality as well.

Comment: Thanks, your answer answered my question, I guess I asked a wrong question. I would like to know where is the definition of `weight.new()`, I think it's a method under `tensor` class, but I cannot find it from the latest document, the closest I found is from PyTorch version 0.3.1 https://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/tensors.html?highlight=new#torch.Tensor.new

Comment: Its not actually implemenetd in Python, its just exposed in it `torch\_C\__init__.pyi`. the actual implementation is [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/csrc/utils/tensor_new.cpp)

Comment: thanks @Rika, this part is annoying me a lot, how did you find it? how did you find out that it actually comes from a exposed method from that file? What is the thinking progress which lead you to find out the source code? How do you know `new()` is `tensor_new()`

Comment: Follow the hints I already gave you. weight is a `Tensor`, see its definition, you cant find it there, so it must be inherited! go to the `torch._C._TensorBase`, you cant view its implementation, so its not in Python! it must be exposed. back off a bit, view whats been exposed in `torch._C`, viola you found the list. now look for `_TensorBase`, you've got your next hint! follow it, you'll reach the header file that implemenets tensor_new!

Comment: thanks a lot @Rika~! your comment is exactly what I was looking for~! the thought process~! I need to establish this pattern so that I don't need to come back again and again to ask similar questions. Appreciate~!

Answer (score 1):

You can also check source code directly from PyTorch documentation.

See [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.parameters) for `torch.nn.Module.parameters` function (just click orange "Source", which gets you [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/module.html#Module.parameters)).

Source is linked if it isn't written in C/C++/low level, in this case you have to go through GitHub and get around the project.

Comment: thanks, yep reading from the document feels better. Do you know how to find the type of `weight`? I guess it's a tensor, I need to find out the definition of `weight.new()`, otherwise I don't know how to use the `new()` method. could you help please